# Flexbox outside the browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[My Website that needs help...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Um4P.png)

Hello everybody, I have a Flexbox and somehow the flexbox goes outside the browser (see picture). Do you know why?

The 4 containers should stay inside the browser and not go outside of it .....

I want to resize, in order to fit it inside the browser, thanks so much in advance

```css
.grid-box{
    display: grid;

    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:

            "box2 box2 box2 box2 "
            "box2 box2 box2 box2 "
            "box2 box2 box2 box2 "
            "box1 box1 box1 box1 "
            "box1 box1 box1 box1 ";
}



.box1 {
    grid-area: box1;
    background-color: #ff7443;

    margin-right: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}


.box2 {
    grid-area: box2;
    background-color: #3fc3ee;
   margin-top: 10%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:736px) {
    .grid-box {
        display: grid;
        flex: 1;
        flex-basis: content;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:

                "box1 box2 box2 box2 "
                "box1 box2 box2 box2 "
                "box1 box2 box2 box2 "
                "box1 box2 box2 box2 ";
    }


    .box1 {
        grid-area: box1;
        background-color: #ff7443;
        margin-top: 30%;
        margin-right: 4%;
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="grid-box">

    <div class="box1">
     

    </div>

    <div class="box2">

    </div>
```

Comment: flexbox or CSS grid? you are mixing a lot of things in your code ... flex, float, grid, etc

Comment: @gerard please stop clicking automatically on the tidy button  you simply make the formating worse

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't think it can get any worse than the way it is now. If you prefer to see the grid-template-areas on separate lines, that's an easy fix but a subjective preference.

Comment: *a subjective preference* you said it, the OP decided to have this formating so no need to change it because *you* don't like it .. actually the code is readable and clear. Putting all the templates in one line isn't clear at all.